# Merge columns with last value per group

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to get the merge the Date and Current Status columns and make their value equal to that of the last cell in their respective grouping. I don't know enough about DataTables and the row groupings to accomplish this with JavaScript. Simply adjusting the columns with colspan and setting the value as the last row ended up changing it for the entire column regardless of the groupings.

```js
var Rowgroup = function() {

  var initTable = function() {
    var table = $('#table');
    table.DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      order: [
        [0, 'asc']
      ],
      rowGroup: {
        dataSrc: 0,
      }
    });
  };
  return {
    init: function() {
      initTable();
    },
  };
}();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  Rowgroup.init();
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <table class="table table-hover" id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Notes</th>
          <th>Current Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>808</td>
          <td>5/1/2018</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum ut porta.</td>
          <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>808</td>
          <td>5/1/2018</td>
          <td>Netus blandit ante felis.</td>
          <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>808</td>
          <td>5/1/2018</td>
          <td>Vel fusce tortor.</td>
          <td>Inactive</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>698</td>
          <td>5/15/2018</td>
          <td>Per sit commodo.</td>
          <td>Inactive</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>698</td>
          <td>5/15/2018</td>
          <td>Hendrerit imperdiet.</td>
          <td>Inactive</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>698</td>
          <td>5/15/2018</td>
          <td>Class augue phasellus.</td>
          <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>698</td>
          <td>5/15/2018</td>
          <td>Ante aliquet.</td>
          <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I had a chance to test it out this morning. This was a huge help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I got your point, you need to append to each group header certain text (date and status) from the last row within the group.

If that's what you've been after, you may:

- grab all the last rows within each group as previous adjacent siblings of group row headers (having default class 'dtrg-group'), plus last row of the table (for the last group):

```
const groupBottomRows = $('.dtrg-group').prev().add('tbody tr:last');
```

- iterate over those rows, extract `date` and `status` from columns 2 and 4 (indexes 1, 3, respectively):

```
const [date, status] = $(this).find('td:eq(1),td:eq(3)').toArray().map(td => $(td).text());
```

- append those to preceding group row header:

```
const groupHeader = $(this).prevAll('.dtrg-group').first().find('td');
$(groupHeader).text($(groupHeader).text() + `: ${date}, ${status}`);
```

The complete **live demo** of that approach you may find below:

```js
const table = $('#table').DataTable({
 responsive: true,
 rowGroup: {dataSrc: 0}
});

const groupBottomRows = $('.dtrg-group').prev().add('tbody tr:last');
$.each(groupBottomRows, function(){
 const [date, status] = $(this).find('td:eq(1),td:eq(3)').toArray().map(td => $(td).text());
 const groupHeader = $(this).prevAll('.dtrg-group').first().find('td');
 $(groupHeader).text($(groupHeader).text() + `: ${date}, ${status}`);
});
```

```html
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.0/css/rowGroup.dataTables.min.css" /><script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script><script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.0/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script></head><body><div><table class="table table-hover" id="table"><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Date</th><th>Notes</th><th>Current Status</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>808</td><td>5/1/2018</td><td>Lorem ipsum ut porta.</td><td>Active</td></tr><tr><td>808</td><td>5/1/2018</td><td>Netus blandit ante felis.</td><td>Active</td></tr><tr><td>808</td><td>5/1/2018</td><td>Vel fusce tortor.</td><td>Inactive</td></tr><tr><td>698</td><td>5/15/2018</td><td>Per sit commodo.</td><td>Inactive</td></tr><tr><td>698</td><td>5/15/2018</td><td>Hendrerit imperdiet.</td><td>Inactive</td></tr><tr><td>698</td><td>5/15/2018</td><td>Class augue phasellus.</td><td>Active</td></tr><tr><td>698</td><td>5/15/2018</td><td>Ante aliquet.</td><td>Active</td></tr></tbody></table></div></body>
```